# Unable to connect to FCM. Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=2001

Tags: objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send from my iOS-Objective-C app a message using:

```
    NSInteger iTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSString *strID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%ld", setting.uid, (long)iTime];
    NSDictionary *msg = @{@"title": @"My iOS-APP",
                          @"text": @"Message from the app"};
    [[FIRMessaging messaging]sendMessage:msg to:setting.uid  withMessageID:strID timeToLive:240];
```

My app connect correctly to FCM in the AppDelegate. But when sending the message above, after a couple of minutes I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to FCM. Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=2001 "(null)"
```

Searching in the last days I have found a lot of suggesting, but even applying them, I don't success in sending the message. Hopefully someone out there SO had the same problem and found the solution.

Comment: FCM can only send messages upstream to an application server. So your setting.uid needs to be the Sender ID of your Firebase project. Then when your app server receives the message it can relay it to a client with the uid. Seems like you are trying to do device to device messaging which is not yet possible

Answer (score 13):

This code error 2001 is shown because, When you send the message the application is already connected to FCM. You are trying to connected again to FCM that is the reason the message. Some part of your code When you are trying send message you try to connect again.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Added to the class the Notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sendDataMessageFailure:) name:FIRMessagingSendErrorNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sendDataMessageSuccess:) name:FIRMessagingSendSuccessNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didDeleteMessagesOnServer) name:FIRMessagingMessagesDeletedNotification object:nil];
```

and get the feedback:

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x15df4f120 {
    name = com.firebase.messaging.notif.send-success;
    userInfo = {
        messageID = ZisMh2OdBsVgjhUlWx9xKnZ3nTk1489164725;
    }
}
```

so it seams the message was send, now the question is, how to retrieve the message, I thought it will be delivered as Push Notification.